# left outer join with EF in-memory data crashes but works fine with SqlServer

Tags: entity-framework

I have run into this in a couple places while unit testing. I write a query like this using a left outer join:

```
from user in db.SSUserInfo
from purchase in db.Purchases.Where(p => p.UserId == user.Id && p.PackageGroupId == Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
where userIdList.contains(user.
select new {
    purchaseId = (int?)purchase.Id
}
```

This works fine when querying against the database even though purchase will be Null if no purchases exist for the user. However, when querying against an in memory list (for unit testing), when purchase returns as null, this crashes with a NULL Reference Exception.

I can get the in-memory version to not crash by doing:

```
purchaseId = (int?)((purchase != null) ? purchase.Id : null)
```

but that causes bloat in the SQL sent to the database.

Does anybody know how to get the in-memory query to not crash on null and at the same time keep the SQL efficient?

This is happening with EF 6.2.0 and .Net 4.6.1. It happened on earlier versions too.

Comment: Can you further define "crash"? Exception, if so, what type? .NET process access violation? BSOD?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is anything you can until `?.` is implemented in LINQ.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I updated the question with Null Reference Exception (on the purchase.Id instruction). and the EF and .Net versions.